# Looking for identity server option for our product

Tags: c#, oauth, identityserver4

i'm c# developer and looking for identity server solution for our online product.

we have:
web API
mobile app
backoffice website

the most important issues i'm looking is:
1.we need to authenticate our users + get their security roles
2.be able to sign out user from our servers- for user turn's inactive due to internal process(decline credit card charge, etc) or in another words,
make the identityserver invalidate all existing client cookies

i started to examine IdentityServer4 i can't find the option to signout user from the server.

can someone advise?

Comment: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html

Comment: the only option there is "Back-channel server-side clients"
but the only example of it must send the actual client token which is no good for me.
i want to be able sign out client with client id only